# Bash Reuse Process Substitution File

Tags: bash, io-redirection, process-substitution

I have a big script which takes a file as input and does various stuff with it. Here is a test version:

```
echo "cat: $1"
cat $1
echo "grep: $1"
grep hello $1
echo "sed: $1"
sed 's/hello/world/g' $1
```

I want my script to work with process substitution, but only the first command (`cat`) works, while the rest don't. I think this is because it is a pipe.

```
$ myscript.sh <(echo hello)
```

should print:

```
cat: /dev/fd/63
hello
grep: /dev/fd/63
hello
sed: /dev/fd/63
world
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why don't you redirect the `$1` to temp file? `cat $1 >/tmp/tempfile` and use the temp file for rest of the work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<(…)` construct creates a pipe. The pipe is passed via a file name like `/dev/fd/63`, but this is a special kind of file: opening it really means duplicating file descriptor 63. (See the end of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/file-descriptor-vs-file-name/18269#18269) for more explanations.)

Reading from a pipe is a destructive operation: once you've caught a byte, you can't throw it back. So your script needs to save the output from the pipe. You can use a temporary file (preferable if the input is large) or a variable (preferable if the input is small). With a temporary file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat <"$1" >"$tmp"
cat <"$tmp"
grep hello <"$tmp"
sed 's/hello/world/g' <"$tmp"
rm -f "$tmp"
```

(You can combine the two calls to `cat` as `tee <"$1" -- "$tmp"`.) With a variable:

```
tmp=$(cat)
printf "%s\n"
printf "%s\n" "$tmp" | grep hello
printf "%s\n" "$tmp" | sed 's/hello/world/g'
```

Note that command substitution `$(…)` truncates all newlines at the end of the command's output. To avoid that, add an extra character and strip it afterwards.

```
tmp=$(cat; echo a); tmp=${tmp%a}
printf "%s\n"
printf "%s\n" "$tmp" | grep hello
printf "%s\n" "$tmp" | sed 's/hello/world/g'
```

*By the way, **don't forget the double quotes around variable substitutions.***

Comment: storing unbounded data in a variable?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I don't understand your comment.

Comment: sorry, I read the 2nd/3rd solutions but missed the condition "preferable if the input is small" which was actually written, but too far above.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. Any reason why you use <"$tmp" in your commands instead of just "$tmp" e.g. `grep hello "$tmp"`? Can I `cp "$1" "$tmp"` to create the tmp file instead of `cat`?

Comment: @dogbane Mostly it's a matter of style. `<"$tmp"` makes it visually obvious that you're reading from the file, it's less clear with `cat "$tmp"` (which reads, whereas `tee "$tmp"` writes, and `cp "$a" "$b"` reads from `$a` and writes to `$b`). For `grep` there's a difference: `grep hello "$tmp" shows the name of the temporary file (which is useless).`

Comment: @Gilles `grep hello "$tmp"` would not show the name of the temp file. It would print out matching lines.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a file, you can read its data many times.  When you use a named pipe (what is actually created by process substitution), you can only read it once.  So the `grep` and `sed` commands receive empty input.

([How to understand pipes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18117/how-to-understand-pipes/18135#18135) might be a good reading.)

To so what you want to do with process substitution, you could write something like:

```
cat $1 | tee >(echo "cat: $1"; cat) | tee >(echo "grep: $1"; grep hello) | (echo "sed: $1"; sed 's/hello/world/g')
```

But in this case, the 2nd `cat`, `grep` and `sed` would be run in parallel, and their output interleaved.  This might be more useful:

```
cat $1 | tee >(cat > cat.txt) | tee >(grep hello > grep.txt) | sed 's/hello/world/g' > sed.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to make the `$1` parameter optional.
Then, one can define `FILE=${1-/dev/stdin}` and use `FILE` several times. However reading several times on a pipe will read sequentially, data will not be duplicated.

The easiest solution to this issue would be to use some temporary file.

```
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then FILE=$(mktemp); cat >FILE; else FILE=$1; fi
```

If you wish to explicitly pass some filename (eventually `/dev/fd/x`), the same temporary file trick can be used:

```
FILE=$(mktemp); cat "$1" >FILE
```

You could also make complex use of `tee` to duplicate input from stdin filedescriptor to several other filedescriptors. But this last method would be quite heavy.

Comment: $1 isn't empty. It is `<(echo hello)` which evaluates to a file in `/dev/fd`.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked. This construct is not something like `<<<hello`.

Answer (score 0):

I file obtained by a process substitution is not seekable, depending on the underlying implementation, so you cannot read it more than once.